# Azure Application Insights for Worker Role

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-cloud-services, azure-application-insights

I am setting up Application Insights for a worker role, and the documentation states:

> Add the Application Insights for Web NuGet package. This version of the SDK includes modules that add server context such as role information. For worker roles, use Application Insights for Windows Services.

I cannot find a a Windows Service version of the Nuget package.
Does anyone know what it is called (if it exists)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need these nuget packages:

```
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights

  Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept
  Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector
  Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector
  Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener
  Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web
  Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.TelemetryChannel
```

Here https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home/tree/master/Samples/AzureEmailService/WorkerRoleB you can find a sample of a project that is set up with documentation.

be sure to read the chapter: Report Dependencies

Comment: Thanks, that looks like exactly what I need. It's pretty annoying that the official documenation references something that doesn't actually exist though. It should at least point you at this page.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need Web. You need Windows **Server** (not service). Nuget package is here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer/

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that instead

Comment: Is there anything else I need to do inside the application, other than add TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"); ?At the moment, uncaught exceptions in my worker role aren't showing up in Application Insights?

Comment: WindowsServer nuget adds UnhandledExceptions module to your configuration file (make sure that config is copied to the output and gets deployed with your application): https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-server-dotnet/blob/master/Src/WindowsServer/WindowsServer.Shared/UnhandledExceptionTelemetryModule.cs. If you exception is really unhandled and leads to application crash we should have good chances to send it before domain unloads. But we have only 1 try and need internet connection for that. If your application is handled somewhere you need to call TrackException from there.

Comment: BTW if you have VS 2015 Update 1 you can open properties of your worker role and in Configuration under Diagnostics select "Enable Diagnostics->Send diagnostics data to Application Insights". In that case WAD traces will be sent to AI and you can get WAD exceptions in case of crashes.